# Describe nodes api call in Kubernetes

Tags: api, kubernetes, nodes, kubectl

Is it possible to use [kubernetes python client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/tree/master/kubernetes/client/api) library in order to get output similar to `kubectl describe nodes` ?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, you can use it to do the same task mostly you are doing with **kubectl**.

**kubectl** itself is one type of client that you are using.

**Example** :

```
from kubernetes import client, config


def main():
    config.load_kube_config()

    api_instance = client.CoreV1Api()

    # Listing the cluster nodes
    node_list = api_instance.list_node()

    print("%s\t\t%s" % ("NAME", "LABELS"))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Example ref : https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/examples/node_labels.py

**EDIT**

```
res_pods = v1.list_pod_for_all_namespaces(pretty=True)
for i in res_pods.items:
    for j in i.spec.containers:
        if j.resources.requests or j.resources.limits:
            print(i.spec.node_name, j.name, j.resources)
```

Comment: That's nice, but it corresponds to the `kubectl get nodes -o json` , I corrected my original question, I am looking for the output same as for `kubectl describe node`. What would be the equivalent API call?

Comment: updated answer feel free to read this nice issue how kubectl and API works : https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/issues/670

Comment: you can also get kubectl api idea which is using in backend